# Python won't run batch file, can't find

Tags: python, git, anaconda, git-bash, python-3.10

So I am currently trying to run Stable Diffusion on my pc via Anaconda Python and Git Bash. It is my first time fiddling around with both python and git.

I always seems to be wanting to use the Microsoft Store Version over the manually installed versions.

Thanks in advance for any advice and sorry if I am too dumb to see something obvious!

Every time I try to run the file I get the following:
`$ ./webui-user.bat`

```
venv "C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\stable_diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
No Python at '"C:\Users\lukas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
```

Is there any way to use a specific python.exe to run a batch? When I run the where python command in the Anaconda Prompt I can see the following paths:
`(base) C:\Windows\system32>where python`

```
C:\Users\lukas\AppData\Local\Continuum\python.exe
C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\lukas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Comment: I am not sure if there is enough information in your question... What is in `.bat` file, what is it doing ?

Comment: There's a mix of two OSes here. Windows, and a the MSYS unix emulation layer in which bash runs. The problem could very well be related to that. Note that the direct cause of the error is the `"` in the name of the executable.